# Dell e6250 notebook won't connect to TV with HDMI cable after installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, dell-latitude, lg-monitor

I am unable to connect my Dell E6250 notebook to my LG LED TV (32 inch) using the HDMI cable. The TV indicates that there is no signal.

This laptop was recently upgraded to windows 7 and has since given this problem. When XP was loaded, I was able to connect and duplicate the view using the function F5 keys.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you run the WIndows 7 upgrade assistant to make sure your hardware would work with Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard for the FN key combinations and it's software specific to that laptop that makes the various key combinations work. Download and install such software for your laptop and OS version.

Windows 7 also has the shortcut Windows Key + P to bring up mirror/internal/external options.